# Formatting posts with the forem gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with html formatting using the forem gem.

Inside of _post.html.erb you will find this line: `<%= forem_format(post.text) %>`

However, when I view a post I see the html in the output.. for example if I input `<b> HI </b>` I see that exact line in the output.

I did try installing the RedCloth gem and then put `<%= RedCloth.new(post.text).to_html %>` This did not produce an error, but unfortunately I still see only `<b> HI </b>` in the output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but wondering ? did you try html_safe

`<%= RedCloth.new(post.text).to_html.html_safe %>`